# How to always initialise prop of this reactjs component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used `react-router` to define the following routes:

```
<Route
  path="/plan"
  components={App}
>
  <Route
    path="try/:planCategory"
    components={PlanTrialContainer}
  />
  <Route
    path="pay/:planCategory"
    components={PlanPurchaseContainer}
  />
</Route>
```

The idea is that: when a user visits url `/plan`, he will see a plan overview by default, otherwise the content will be decided by `try/...` or `pay/...`

Here is the `App` class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu } from './Menu';
import PlansOverviewContainer from './PlansOverviewContainer';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props.children;

    let component = null;
    if (children) {
      component = children;
    } else {
      component = PlansOverviewContainer;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        {component}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I will get this error message when I try the `/plan`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
App.render
/Users/antkong/dev/myproject/plan/app/scripts/components/App.js
```

If I change the line from

```
const { children } = this.props.children;
```

to

```
const children = this.props ? this.props.children : null;
```

It will work.

However my preferred version is the first version i.e. `this.props` should be initialised no matter what. How can I ensure `prop` is initialised? Is there any parameter to the `Router` component I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring children from `this.props.children` which is like trying to do:
`this.props.children.children`

Instead change it to:

`const { children } = this.props;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the super-classes initializer like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu } from './Menu';
import PlansOverviewContainer from './PlansOverviewContainer';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props.children;

    let component = null;
    if (children) {
      component = children;
    } else {
      component = PlansOverviewContainer;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        {component}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The addition of the constructor does not change anything. See my answer.